How to create multiple Signings for different environments (stage, prod, etc), for a single target in Xcode?
I have inherited an app which supports multiple targets, with differentiated bundle ID for prod vs stage/debug.
I am trying to recreate the implementation seen in the image below, but without success. Specifically, for a single target, I want to have Signing (Debug and Staging) which uses a bundle ID, and for Signing (Production), a different Bundle ID.
Trying the following yielded no results:

Duplicating Capabilities
Duplicating targets per this walkthrough, though realized it is not possible to then "combine" the targets
Following the SO question described here, though it also required multiple targets which was not what I had intended to do

Any recommendations on how I can approach this would be much appreciated. Thanks!

